# Generate Braille characters from a dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, iteration

## Problem

I would like to generate Braille characters from a dictionary as below which store the n-th active bits:-

```
private static readonly int BrailleStringSize = 6;

Dictionary<char, int[]> BrailleDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int[]>
{
    { 'a', new int[] { 1 } },               // 100000
    { 'b', new int[] { 1, 2 } },            // 110000
    { 'c', new int[] { 1, 4 } },            // 100100
    { 'd', new int[] { 1, 4, 5 } },         // 100110
    { 'e', new int[] { 1, 5 } },            // 100010
    { 'f', new int[] { 1, 2, 4 } },         // 110100
    { 'g', new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 } },      // 110110
    { 'h', new int[] { 1, 2, 5 } },         // 110010
    { 'i', new int[] { 2, 4 } },            // 010100
    { 'j', new int[] { 2, 4, 5 } },         // 010110
    { 'k', new int[] { 1, 3 } },            // 101000
    { 'l', new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } },         // 111000
    { 'm', new int[] { 1, 3, 4 } },         // 101100
    { 'n', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5 } },      // 101110
    { 'o', new int[] { 1, 3, 5 } },         // 101010
    { 'p', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } },      // 111100
    { 'q', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } },   // 111110
    { 'r', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 } },      // 111010
    { 's', new int[] { 2, 3, 4 } },         // 011100
    { 't', new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 } },      // 011110
    { 'u', new int[] { 1, 3, 6 } },         // 101001
    { 'v', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 6 } },      // 111001
    { 'w', new int[] { 2, 4, 5, 6 } },      // 010111
    { 'x', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 } },      // 101101
    { 'y', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 } },   // 101111
    { 'z', new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6 } }       // 101011
};
```

in which the a Braille character is a string with length of 6 while 0 and 1 represents bumps and dots.

## Algorithm 1

```
private static void PrintBrailleString1()
{
    foreach (var entry in BrailleDictionary)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= BrailleStringSize; i++)
        {
            output.Append(Array.IndexOf(entry.Value, i) > -1 ? '1' : '0');
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{ entry.Key } => { output }");
    }
}
```

This solution is quite naive but run **FASTEST** among the 3.

## Algorithm 2

```
private static void PrintBrailleString2()
{
    foreach (var entry in BrailleDictionary)
    {
        var output         = new StringBuilder();
        var activeBitQueue = new Queue<int>(entry.Value);

        for (int i = 1; i <= BrailleStringSize && output.Length != 6; i++)
        {
            if (activeBitQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                var top = activeBitQueue.Peek();

                if (i < top)
                {
                    output.Append('0');
                }
                else if (i == top)
                {
                    output.Append('1');
                    activeBitQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output.Append(new string('0', BrailleStringSize - i + 1));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{ entry.Key } => { output }");
    }
}
```

Here I attempt to skip unnecessary call of `Array.IndexOf` but the solution turns out really ugly and performs moderately.

## Algorithm 3

```
private static void PrintBrailleString3()
{
    foreach (var entry in BrailleDictionary)
    {
        var output = new string(Enumerable.Range(1, BrailleStringSize)
                                    .Select(b => Array.IndexOf(entry.Value, b) > -1 ?
                                                    '1' : '0').ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine($"{ entry.Key } => { output }");
    }
}
```

This is a one-liner approach using LINQ and it performs the **SLOWEST**.

## Test

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopWatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        // Test with commented Console.WriteLine
        PrintBrailleString1();
        //PrintBrailleString2();
        //PrintBrailleString3();
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken: { stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds } ms");
}
```

## Questions

1. Why algorithm 2 is so slower compared to algorithm 1?
2. Should I sacrifice performance for readability by using algorithm 3?

## Add-ons

Are there any cleaner ways to perform similar operations?

Comment: How did you measure thier performance?

Comment: I'm using `StopWatch` in the main class to keep track the elapse time with 100k iterations. Should I include it in the question too?

Comment: It would be nice if you included it too. Otherwise you will probably have to answer this quesiton a few more times depending who asks what ;-)

Comment: Alright I'll update the question in few minutes. Thanks for the feedback @t3chb0t!

Comment: One more tip. Measure them once more but without wrinting to the console. My measurements say that the first one is the fastest, then comes the second one and the last one is the slowest.

Comment: You might want to wait a day or 2 to accept to encourage other answers.

Comment: @Paparazzi yes you're right! I should read more about etiquettes in meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## improvable

> ```
> var output = new StringBuilder();
>
> for (int i = 1; i <= BrailleStringSize; i++)
> {
>   output.Append(Array.IndexOf(entry.Value, i) > -1 ? '1' : '0');
> }
> ```

This is the only part that you actually can optimze. Eeach of the three algorithms does this and only the second one is a slightly different way. Not suprisingly LINQ kills it's performance of the last solution.

---

Currently you loop over all six items for each letter (`i <= BrailleStringSize`), even if there are only two or three bumps. This is not necessary.

What you could do, is to create a string with all zeros `new string('0', 6)` an then insert `1` at the appropriate indexes `letter[bump - 1] = '1';` looping over the bumps `foreach (var bump in entry.Value)` without searching anything. As it tunrns out, this need only 1/3 of the time of the first algorithm which was the fastetst.

```
var zeros = new string('0', 6);
foreach (var entry in BrailleDictionary)
{
    var letter = new StringBuilder(zeros);
    foreach (var bump in entry.Value)
    {
        letter[bump - 1] = '1';
    }       

    //Console.WriteLine($"{ entry.Key } => { letter }");
}
```

During your tests you should disable the console output. It might signifficantly affect the measurementes.

---

## measurements (for fun)

If you are curious how I measured them, this is the helper I used:

```
private static void Measure(Action action, int iterations, string name)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) action();
    sw.Elapsed.Dump(name);
}
```

and all four calls:

```
var count = 1_000_000;
Measure(() => PrintBrailleString1(), count, "OP1");
Measure(() => PrintBrailleString2(), count, "OP2");
Measure(() => PrintBrailleString3(), count, "OP3");
Measure(() => PrintBrailleString4(), count, "t3chb0t");
Measure(() => PrintBrailleString5(), count, "Paparazzi");
```

According to my tests the results are as follows:

```
OP1

00:00:04.4152571 


OP2

00:00:05.0145808 


OP3

00:00:11.6835103 


t3chb0t

00:00:01.8342203 


Paparazzi

00:00:03.6927934
```

---

## performance vs convenience

> Should I sacrifice performance by using algorithm 3?

It depends. Usually it doesn't matter and you can pick the most convinient solution (most of the time it's LINQ - although here it doesn't have any advantages).

Your measurements show that all three algorithms run quite good but the longer they run the larnger the differences are. If you are going to translate a few books into Braille it might be important to optimize the speed and chose the fastest solution but if you only play with single words or sentences the user will never notice any difference so you don't have to go crazy about the peroformance.

Optimize only if it's noticable to the user not because an artifical test shows signifficant differences for an *insane* number of items.

Comment: Wow that's a great insight from you and thanks for sharing your knowledge! I've tried to perform edit but unfortunately keep getting error about code formatting issue although I've make sure all the code line starts with 4 space in Notepad++. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Yes you're right! In most situation the straightforward way would be initialize the dictionary with "translated" string instead of integer array. I'm trying to learn different approaches whereby the storage is a constraint in this case by only storing active bits. Thanks again for clearing my doubt!

Comment: @Zephyr _Why algorithm 2 is so much slower compared to others?_ Regarding this question. I know that linq runs slower and knew the details once but I can no longer explain this. Let's hope someone else will be able to answer this later ;-)

Comment: @Zephyr _initialize the dictionary with "translated" string_ exactly, I thought it might be just for experimenting so I didn't mention this _issue_ :-]

Comment: Well found out it's my mistake for ignoring a newline after indented code line during editing. The idea of skipping extraneous call by using `Queue` seems to be overcomplicating the problem and "oversmart". Your "bit switching" strategy nailed it!

Comment: This is an off-topic question: Your helper method looks really cool to me! May I know why I couldn't print the function name using your method by calling `action.Method.Name`?

Comment: @Zephyr because this is an anonymous method and doesn't really have a _usable_ name.

Answer (score 3):

Bit mashing might be fastest
Assign to variable 1,000,000 times in under 10 seconds

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
Dictionary<char, int[]> BrailleDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int[]>
                        {   { 'a', new int[] { 1 } },               // 100000
                            { 'b', new int[] { 1, 2 } },            // 110000
                            { 'c', new int[] { 1, 4 } },            // 100100
                            { 'd', new int[] { 1, 4, 5 } },         // 100110
                            { 'e', new int[] { 1, 5 } },            // 100010
                            { 'f', new int[] { 1, 2, 4 } },         // 110100
                            { 'g', new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 } },      // 110110
                            { 'h', new int[] { 1, 2, 5 } },         // 110010
                            { 'i', new int[] { 2, 4 } },            // 010100
                            { 'j', new int[] { 2, 4, 5 } },         // 010110
                            { 'k', new int[] { 1, 3 } },            // 101000
                            { 'l', new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } },         // 111000
                            { 'm', new int[] { 1, 3, 4 } },         // 101100
                            { 'n', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5 } },      // 101110
                            { 'o', new int[] { 1, 3, 5 } },         // 101010
                            { 'p', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } },      // 111100
                            { 'q', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } },   // 111110
                            { 'r', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 } },      // 111010
                            { 's', new int[] { 2, 3, 4 } },         // 011100
                            { 't', new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 } },      // 011110
                            { 'u', new int[] { 1, 3, 6 } },         // 101001
                            { 'v', new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 6 } },      // 111001
                            { 'w', new int[] { 2, 4, 5, 6 } },      // 010111
                            { 'x', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 } },      // 101101
                            { 'y', new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 } },   // 101111
                            { 'z', new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6 } }       // 101011
                        };
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int[]> c in BrailleDictionary)
    {
        //9,570
        int b = 0;
        foreach (int pos in c.Value)
        {
            b |= 1 << 6 - pos;
        }
        string br = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(6, '0');
        //Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", c.Key, Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(6, '0'));

        //var zeros = new string('0', 6);
        //foreach (var entry in BrailleDictionary)
        //{
        //    //11,340
        //    var letter = new StringBuilder(zeros);
        //    foreach (var bump in entry.Value)
        //    {
        //        letter[bump - 1] = '1';
        //    }
        //    string br = letter.ToString();
        //    //Debug.WriteLine($"{ entry.Key } => { letter }");
        //}
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
```

Comment: The bit operation is fast, indeed but turning the int into a string makes it the second fastest solution and since this part is crucial it cannot be skipped. Sorry, I mean fastest, right behind mine, if it was a competition lol.

Comment: @t3chb0t Not by my test.  To be fair need to include a call to StringBuilder ToString();

Comment: I just did and it added merely 2ms.

Comment: @t3chb0t OK we got different test results.

Comment: @Paparazzi Thank you for showing another approach in solving this problem. It takes me some time to figure out what you did there, interesting base 2 manipulation!